# How to get ajax post data

Tags: cordova

I am developing a login form that is submitted via the ajax command, the data is sent to a php file where it is processed and a json object is returned but i am having some trouble getting the json object back to into the ajax command as it keeps returning **null**, the code i am using is as follows...

$.ajax({

```
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'my local url',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: postData,
                success: function(ans, textStatus, jqXHR){

                 alert(ans);

                 response = jQuery.parseJSON(ans);
                 alert(response);

                 alert("Respose:" +textStatus);


                },
               error: function(){

               alert('error!');


                }
            });
```

Comment: I sloved my proble , the problem is server side return function. I replace return to print work well, thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this one

```
formData = {
    // all your parameters here
    param1: param1,
    param2: param2
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "https://www.example.com/test",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        //success handling
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //error handling
    }
});
```